# adf.test returning p-value > 0.99 even when data is stationary

Tags: stationarity, unit-root, granger-causality

I have a pair of time series that I differenced and now take on values {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}.  My goal is to test them for Granger causality and discover any lead/lag relationships.  Since this requires the time series to be stationary, I ran adf.test on them and was surprised to find that the p-value for both were 0.99.  I also got a warning saying p-value greater than printed p-value.  I was hoping to learn what I'm doing wrong here, please let me know what further information I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My data was xts, adf.test doesn't support xts so it worked once I used as.zoo